# Evaluating triple bounded integral for 3-sum

Tags: discrete-mathematics, definite-integrals, algorithms

I want to evaluate 3-sum array access operation $n(n-1)(n-2)$

> Ex 3. 3-sum triple loop. $$\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N\sum_{k=1}^N1\sim\int_{x=1}^N\int_{y=x}^N\int_{z=y}^N\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx\sim\frac16N^3$$

I want to estimate $n^3 - 3n^2 + 2n$ using triple integrals $\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$ and the result should be the one in picture that I attached. I did the evaluation but I'm not getting the result correct my leading term is $n^6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\int_{1}^Ndx\int_{y=x}^Ndy\int_{z=y}^N dz = \int_{1}^Ndx\int_{y=x}^Ndy(N-y)=\int_{1}^Ndx\left[Ny-\frac{y^2}{2}\right]_{x}^N = \int_1^N dx\left[\frac{N^2}{2}-Nx+\frac{x^2}{2}\right]
$$
the last part will get what you want.

$\textbf{edit:}$
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{y=x}^Ndy(N-y) &=& \int_{y=x}^NNdy - \int_{y=x}^Nydy\\
 &=& \left[Ny\right]_{y=x}^N-\left[\frac{y^2}{2}\right]_{y=x}^N\\
&=&N^2-Nx-\frac{N^2}{2}-\frac{x^2}{2}\\
&=&\frac{N^2}{2}-Nx-\frac{x^2}{2}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Can you explain steps of evaluating dz,dy

Comment: because $$\int_{z=y}^{z=N}1\cdot dz = \left[z\right]_{z=y}^{z=N}=N-y$$/ does it make more sense?